# Programmatically Changing the Contents of a Webview in Electron

Tags: javascript, html, webview, electron

So in my electron app I have a main page with a sidebar (containing some links) and then a webview taking up most of the page. I have some pages in separate .html files that I would like to be able to load in to the webview programmatically. With iFrames it's as easy as setting the name attribute of the iframe (say to "content_frame") then having my links as something like:

```
<a id="page1_link" href="pages/page1.html" target="content_frame">page 1</a>
```

And this is my webview:

```
<webview nodeintegration="on" src="pages/landing_page.html" name="content_frame" height="100%" width="100%"></webview>
```

The first page (landing_page.html) shows up fine, but if I try and use a webview in the same way however, it will open the page in a popup window, and not in this embedded webview. I have been using iframes for this up until now but I need to use node stuff from electron (require from an iframe breaks everything).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like there is a clean way to do this using the target attribute of the anchor tag. With some JavaScript you could capture the anchor's click event and use loadURL on the webview to change the page. There are definitely more elegant ways of doing this, but this works:

```
var webview = document.getElementsByName('content_frame')[0];
var bound = false;
webview.addEventListener("dom-ready", function() {
    if (bound) return;
    bound = true;               
    var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (var a = 0; a < anchors.length; a++) {
        var anchor = anchors[a];
        if (anchor.getAttribute('target') == 'content_frame') {
            anchor.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                webview.loadURL(e.srcElement.href);                
            });
        }
    }                                
});
```

You will, however, have to provide the protocol according to the documentation here: http://electron.atom.io/docs/v0.37.4/api/web-view-tag/#webviewloadurlurl-options:

> Loads the url in the webview, the url must contain the protocol prefix, e.g. the http:// or file://.

Comment: thanks for the response, I ended up just manually changing the src value using a function call, but I'll keep a hold of your response, turns out webviews come with their own load of issues so I'm gonna switch back to iframes for a bit. I'm about to open a new question on using require() from within an iframe if you have any input on that it would be very welcome.